Display a static image with GLFW in case it is not possible to configure a hardware accelerated surface
What is a platform independent way of displaying a static image with GLFW without a working rendering context?
Creating a rendering context may fail for multiple reasons:

The API is not supported by the installed driver/hardware combination

The driver/kernel has been updated and a reboot would solve the issue

The application is running remotely over ssh with X11 forwarding with no driver support


Instead of returning back to the desktop, I would like to inform the user that the application could not be launched. The solution should work on all backends that GLFW supports.

In short: not possible, unless you aquire the native window handle and use the platform specific drawing routines but then platform independency goes out of the window. In this case, SDL would be an alternative (which would handle the platform dependent rendering part).
